# Warning: include(FME/Manufacturers/Controller/Router.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, magento

Ive been trying for hours to figure out why this magento install will not work. At first it may look like a normal error and im missing a file, but in reality thats not the case. The controller

```
FME_Manufacturers_Controller
```

doesn't exist anymore and i'm sure its from an old extension. I cant seem to find anything in the codebase that has to do with the FME controller and I was wondering if this controller can be called from the database. If so, what table? The error is from line 93 in `/lib/Varien/Autoload.php`

Answer (score 0):

Magento loads controllers and its action like so:

```php
// @see Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard::match
// instantiate controller class
$controllerInstance = Mage::getControllerInstance($controllerClassName, $request, $front->getResponse());
```

First to find the place where the controller is loaded from you could search your Magento installation for `Mage::getControllerInstance('FME_Manufacturers` for example.

Second is you could look for lines like `<?php echo $this->getUrl('frontname/controllername/action') ?>`. Often this is used in templates to call controllers and their actions.

Another thing is, if you follow the error backtrace you should be able to see there this call comes from, shouldn't you?

To call a controller from database is not possible. The only thing is that a static block or a CMS page is including a template and in this template the controller is called. But you would find this place by scanning through all template files in `app/design` looking for `FME`.